# Function invoke issue in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

everyone!
I am a newbie in mobile development by Flutter, so I am struggling with the following issue.
This is a code snip inside "layout" tutorial at https://flutter.dev/.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWG64.png)

I appreciate that someone let me know about good solutions.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to define color as a constant or static:

```
Color color = const Color(0xFF42A5F5);
```

or

```
static const Color color = const Color(0xFF42A5F5);
```

you can see the flutter color chart here

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Colors-class.html

Comment: Thanks for your offer.
As you see an image, it has been invoked a function called _buildButtonColumn, but it displays an errors. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: if you change the shape you are declaring the color will solve, because the problem is in the "context"

I made an example here and it worked: `Color color = const Color(0xFF42A5F5);`

  `@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildColor(color);
  }`

  `_buildColor(Color color){ }`